# Does no mention of GPS (on selling site) mean there is no GPS?

Tags: gps, sensors, lg-phoenix-2

I'm looking at the AT&T LG Phoenix 2. It does not mention GPS on either Best Buy nor AT&T, and only mentions a cryptic "GPS Service for location accuracy" on LG's site. (Though phonearena.com does mention GPS.)

Can it be that a phone with a GPS antenna would not be mentioned as having one (why?), or is this a sign that it actually doesn't?

Comment: Are there even any phones *at all* that do not come with GPS? I thought that GPS has pretty much been standard for several years, sort of like how it is nearly impossible to buy a new car without air conditioning.